# calculating annualized GDP

Tags: average, economics

I was reading the following: https://thistimeitisdifferent.com/ecb-balance-sheet-july-2019

I'm trying to calculate the Asset / GDP ratio (they get around 40%) for July-19.

The asset number is $4,667,463$ (million euros). Just taking the corresponding GDP figure from the datasource of $2,981,863.20$ (million euros) and dividing gives a much higher ratio.

At the very bottom of the article, they outline the method that they use for GDP as a "rolling four quarter (annualized) average"

How do I calculate the above?

My approach was:

1: Take GDP data (first comment at bottom of the article there is a link), then calculating the % change per quarter.

2: Multiply the % change by 4 to give an annual figure

3: Calculate the average for 4 quarters, then discard that data and move onto the 5th datapoint calculate the average for datapoint 5 to 9 etc.

I don't get anywhere near the 40% number they say in the article...

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_the_European_Union) gives a EU GDP of 18.8 trillion euros in 2018.  The 4.7 trillion ECB balance sheet is close to 40% of this.  I don't know why you are looking at GDP change per quarter instead of just looking up the value, nor where the 2.98 trillion euro GDP comes from.

Comment: I used the data from FRED as given in the article at the bottom of the link, but that gives values much different. I'll just use the yearly for now I guess.